# Postgresql query current year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to see only the current year rows from a table.

Would it be possible filter a timestamp column only by current year parameter, is there some function that can return this value?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE "MYDATE" LIKE CURRENT_YEAR
```

Comment: Look at CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and then using date_part on it ... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date_part('year', mydate) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE);
```

The date_part function is available in all PostgreSQL releases from current down to 7.1 (at least).

Comment: Note that that query will be pretty slow. A better idea would be to do mydate >= date_trunc('year',current_date) AND mydate < date_trunc('year',current_date + interval '1 year')

Comment: Thanks a lot for that hint! Any improvement is very much appreciated. I tried to substantiate what you wrote with some measuring. I ran a test on a table containing about 200K records, some 50 columns overall and having 9 different columns of date or timestamp type. The number of records selected differed from 500 to 30K depending on the column. It took your queries up to 10% longer. The best result was near level. Of course I followed rules of statistical investigation. I guess you tried yourself many times. Someone out there who can come up with her or his own measuring?

Answer (score 19):

This is pretty old, but now you can do:

```sql
SELECT date_part('year', now()); -> 2020
```

In the place of `now` you can pass any timestamp. More on [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this writing

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW());
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW());
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW());
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35328595)